# Errors in including .c and .h files in a c++ program

Tags: linked-list, include, hashset

I am implementing a hashset in c++. I have a c linkedlist implementation that I want to include in my hashset that is comprised of a .c and a .h file. When I compile my .c and .h files together, I don't get any errors, but when I include my .c file in my .cpp file, I get tons of errors from my .h file, particularly regarding conflicting/previous/forward declarations.

I have tried adding include guards to my .h file to make sure things are not being declared multiple times and when I include my .c file in my .cpp file, I use extern "C" to identify it as a c file.